# MySQL: Would INNER JOIN Be The Most Efficient In This Statement?

Tags: mysql

the following MySQL statement takes a very long time to execute, I think because I'm using **gameId IN**.

I think the most efficient way would be to use a **INNER JOIN**, but I'm new to MySQL and I can't come up with the **INNER JOIN** statement. Can you please help me out? If there is a more efficient way than **INNER JOIN**, I would like to use that, I'm just not sure if there is.

Statement that needs to be more efficient:

```
SELECT championId
FROM match_up WHERE
gameId IN
(
    SELECT gameId
    FROM match_up 
    GROUP BY gameId
    HAVING SUM(championId IN (19, 23, 40) AND win = 1) = 3
    AND SUM(championId IN (7, 18) AND win = 0) = 2
)
```

Thank you in advance for the help and knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT m.championId
FROM match_up m INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT gameId
    FROM match_up 
    GROUP BY gameId
    HAVING SUM(championId IN (19, 23, 40) AND win = 1) = 3
    AND SUM(championId IN (7, 18) AND win = 0) = 2
) s ON m.gameID = s.gameID
```

Have a look at the difference between [Row Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/row-subqueries.html) and [Subqueries in the FROM Clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that might perform will with an index on `match_up(gameId, win, championId)`:

```
select *
from match_up m
where 3 = (select count(*)
           from match_up m2
           where m2.gameId = m.gameId and
                 m2.championId IN (19, 23, 40) and
                 m2.win = 1
          ) and
      2 = (select count(*)
           from match_up m2
           where m2.gameId = m.gameId and
                 m2.championId IN (7, 18) and
                 m2.win = 0
          );
```